# How do I create a domain with a dynamic A NAME Record/dynamic IP Resolution?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain

Services like no-ip.com provide domains that resolve to a dynamic IP. My shared hosting provider does not give me privileges to edit the domain records any time I want however if I contact them they can change them for me. Is it possible to create an A NAME Record that resolves to a no-ip domain. I wish to host a server on my dynamic IP and I was thinking to have a A NAME Record that routes to the no-ip domain that then resolves to my IP.

e.g. server.mydomain.com -> servermydomain.no-ip.com -> 000.000.000.000

Comment: sorry about my bad writing. im not very good at explaining

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using a [`CNAME`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME) record that maps to your no-ip domain.

```
www.your-domain.com.        CNAME  yourserver.no-ip.com.
```